# How to inflate a view in a custom adapter correctly?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a custom adapter for an AutoCompleteTextView to dynamically display search results. I am writing this in C# using Xamarin Android. When I create the custom adapter I am trying to inflate a view but my compiler is not recognizing my views as a part of the resource file. Here is my adapter:

```
using System;
using Android;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

public class CustomTrafficSearchAdapter : BaseAdapter
{

    Context context;
    string[] data;
    static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public override int Count
    {
        get;
    }

    public CustomTrafficSearchAdapter(Context context, string[] data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return data[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = View.Inflate(Resource.Layout.autocomplete_textview, null);
        }

        convertView = inflater.Inflate(context, Resource.Layout.autocomplete_textview, null);
        TextView placeNameView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeName);
        TextView placeAddressView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeAddress);

        //TextView text = vi.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
        //text.setText(data[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is my autocomplete layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomAuto"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeName" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeAddress" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my style file:

```
<style name="CustomAuto">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#333</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If the `Resource.designer.cs` is not updating, the number one cause is an invalid axml file. If you build the project, you will receive a `APTXXXX` error with the output of `aapt` (Android Asset Packaging Tool), that will tell you the error in the axml file. Since you did not post your `CustomAuto`, without the `style`, your `LinearLayout` is valid axml, so I will *assume* that the `APT` error will point in you in that direction.

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover, I added my style file. Let me know if anything changes.

Comment: Also I am not getting the APT build error. It cannot find the layouts in the adapter. Is there another problem that could be present?

Comment: Try this : view = inflater.Inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_textview, parent, false)

Comment: @YorkShen that method signature and syntax is for java android. However, I am working with Xamarin Android which is different. I don't believe that method has the same signature in c#. The issue is that Xamarin Studio doesn't even load the layout names from the resource file inside the editor. The issue is not a compiler issue or a runtime issue. Therefore, I cannot even generate an error because I cannot select the layout in the first place.

Comment: convertView = LayoutInflater.FromContext(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.double_textview_layout, null); ended up working

Comment: What is the error message?